Looking for workaround for: When focus is on p-dropdown, tab key does not focus on next item
I have a p-table with editable inputs including a p-dropdown. As soon as the focus is on the p-dropdown, the focus doesn't go to the next input by using the tab key. But when the focus is one a simple text input the focus jumps properly.
I am aware that this issue has been reported to primeng already. And in this issue they even showed a quick fix. But I don't know how to implement it into my application. And maybe there is another workaround?
Anyways, here is the demo where you can't tab through the p-dropdown.
Steps to reproduce:
1. Click on first input text
2. Press tab key to focus on p-dropdown
3. Press Tab key again.
